# Drag n' drop file move in project window not working in IntelliJ IDEA 15?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, intellij-15

The drag-and-drop re-factor move of files in the project window is not working for me in IntelliJ IDEA 15. If I right-click on a file in the project window, select `Refactor -> Move...` from the menu and change the package/folder there it works, but not if I try to drag-and-drop the file from one package to another.

What happens is the dialog appears, but everything is disabled on the dialog box and the only way I can close it is by escaping out (even the close button seems disabled).

This particular IDEA installation is pretty barebones, (no fancy plugins) But perhaps there are some plugin interactions at play. I do have a few other intelliJ installations locally however (a community edition with `cursive` and an older 14 Ultimate).

I've made sure `Enable Drag'n'Drop Functionality in editor` is checked under editor settings as indicated in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-drag-and-drop-in-the-editor.html).

Am I missing something here or is this a bug? A cursory googling and SO search did not reveal anything.

Comment: What exactly are you dragging and where are you dropping?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed recently, and is available as of 15.0.3 EAP build.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146691

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks like a bug. (The setting you mention only affects drag & drop in the editor; drag & drop in the Project view is always enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

It still breaking if you do move the files.

You can solve this by changing the script path at `Run -> Edit Configurations -> select the .py file you moved -> Change script_path to the  latest path`